# What's the difference between stripe default_source and default_payment_method?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using the following code to make a card default:

```
 if ($form_state['input']['default'] == TRUE) {
      // Set the current card as default.
      try {
        $stripe->customers->update(
          $customer['id'],
          ['invoice_settings' => ['default_payment_method' => $card['id']]]
        );
      } catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
        watchdog('store', $e->getMessage(), array(), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
      }
    }
```

because per documentation on https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach and https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method, it's advised to use the `default_payment_method` parameter.

And it works fine marking properly the `$customer['invoice_settings']['default_payment_method']` array value.

However, when I add a new card via Stripe UI, then `$customer['default_source']` gets silently marked for it.

So I wonder what's the difference between them and which one is preferable to use? If the `default_source` is a outdated legacy parameter, then why Stripe's own UI keeps using it?

UPDATE of January 10, 2023: In addition to the accepted answer, here is the update from Stripe support on the subject matter:

[image]

Comment: Can confirm that adding a card to a customer within the Stripe admin results in the card being added to `default_source` instead of `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`invoice_settings.default_payment_method` is the recommended parameter to be set for setting up the default payment method of a customer. `default_source` is the legacy parameter.

Comment: That was my understanding after reading the documentation, however how come that Stripe own UI uses the legacy parameter, if it is indeed a legacy parameter?

Comment: `default_source` is mainly for legacy payment source since some users still use on legacy [Sources API](https://stripe.com/docs/sources) that hasn't moved to [Payment Methods API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods). If your card is legacy source (`card_xxx`), `default_source` will be updated. If the card is a payment method object (`pm_xxx`), `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` will be updated.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer. Though, all the cards were testing cards taken from Stripe's website. So if your theory is right that means either Stripe's testing cards are legacy cards or Stripe's UI is still using legacy methods.